# How to disable reopening desktops after rebooting

Tags: macos, automation, mission-control

Is there a way to disable reopening all the mission control virtual desktops  after rebooting.

For example if I have 4 desktops open and I reboot, I'd like to start fresh with 1. I know I can tear them down manually before I restart, but I would like to automate this step. Is this possible?

Comment: By desktops are you referring to mission control virtual screens or just you don’t want automatic account log in enabled?

Comment: I'm talking about mission control virtual screens.